# include files recursively in Cocoapods podspec

Tags: cocoapods

I want to create a local podspec that is based on some private code. I can't seem to use the 'source' attribute, as that is not working. I can use the 'source_files' attribute, but it does not include files recursively. So with a directory that looks like this

```
Library
  /src
    /Core
    /Audio
    /Graphics
```

And my podspec looks like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  ...
  s.source = 'src' # this does not work.
  s.source_files = 'src' # this only includes the files in src, and not in any of the Core, Audio or Graphics folders.
```

I kind of want to specify a '-r' flag. I have tried using wildcards but no luck.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `source_files` attribute uses [Ruby file glob syntax](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob). The pattern must be relative to the root of your project (i.e., the podspec file), so this should work for you:

```rb
s.source_files = 'Library/src/**/*.{h,m}'
```

The `source` attribute is not for source code files, but rather for the remote repository from which the code should be retrieved (most commonly a Git repository URL and tag). See the [CocoaPods specification docs](http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html) for more info.

Answer (score 8):

**CocoaPods source_files**

[[CocoaPods]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218904/4770877)

```
spec.source_files = 'Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift}', 'More_Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
```

File patterns:

- `*` - Matches any file.
- `**` - Matches directories recursively.
- `?` - Matches any one character.
- `[set]` - Matches any one character in set.
- `{p,q}` - Matches either literal p or literal q.
- `\` - Escapes the next meta-character.