# How to check version of a CocoaPods framework

Tags: ios, version, cocoapods

I have updated Flurry via CocoaPods, but how can I check if Flurry was updated?

I mean the terminal shown me that everything is ok:

```
Installing FlurrySDK (4.2.3)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

but I am not sure that it has been updated.

Comment: Just in case readers come here looking for how to check their version of CocoaPods, the answer to that is type pod --version in bash

Comment: ```$ cat Podfile.lock``` command to trace package version

Comment: You can add grep command to the above comment, to filter a specific pod. In your case with Flurry: `$ cat Podfile.lock | grep FlurrySDK`

Answer (score 324, accepted):

The `Podfile.lock` keeps track of the resolved versions of each Pod installed. If you want to double check that FlurrySDK is using 4.2.3, check that file.

*Note: You should not edit this file. It is auto-generated when you run `pod install` or `pod update`*

Comment: how do we open Podfile.lock? with which application ?

Comment: You can open file with "vim Podfile.lock"

Comment: How do you interpret the Podfile.lock sections.  I see the Pod I care about listed in different sections, each with different version numbers.  Specifically there is a PODS: section, and a DEPENDENCIES: section.

Comment: I open Podfile.lock with XCode

Answer (score 226):

To check version of cocoapods from terminal:

For Sudoless:

```
gem which cocoapods
```

For Sudo:

```
sudo gem which cocoapods
```

Also note: If you want to edit **podfile** or **podfile.lock** don't edit it in editors. Open only with **XCode**.

Comment: thanks, works for me! but just in case checking cocoa pods version. Not just some library version, like in my question which was answered, but maybe your answer  will help someone.

Comment: What happens if we edit those files in editor other than XCode?

Comment: We can open it but if we try to save, it will generate ASCII values and give errors. https://champlintechnologiesllc.com/20_cocoapods_xcode/

Answer (score 210):

**pod --version**

to get the version of installed pod

Comment: Gives the version of cocoapod only, not for the pods installed

Comment: This is incorrect. This command will give the version of `cocoapods` dependency manager, not the versions of individual pods installed. Instead, take a look at `Podfile.lock` to see the installed versions.

Answer (score 166):

```
pod outdated
```

When you run pod outdated, CocoaPods will list all pods that have newer versions that the ones listed in the Podfile.lock (the versions currently installed for each pod) and that could be updated (as long as it matches the restrictions like pod 'MyPod', '~>x.y' set in your Podfile)

Comment: The scheme of a line of pod outdated's output is: - <pod name> <current version> -> <latest version (with restrictions)> (latest version <latest version (without restrictions)>)

Comment: This is the answer to OP's question

Answer (score 41):

**CocoaPods version**

[[iOS Dependency manager]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257708/4770877)

**CocoaPods program version**

`CocoaPods` program that is built with Ruby and it will be installable with the default Ruby available on macOS.

```
pod --version //1.8.0.beta.2
//or
gem which cocoapods //Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods.rb

//install or update
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

**A pod version**

Version of pods that is specified in `Podfile`

`Podfile.lock`

It is located in the same folder as `Podfile`. Here you can find a version of a pod which is used

**Search for pods**

If you are interested in **all** available version of specific pod you can use

```
pod search <pod_name>
//or
pod trunk info <pod_name>
```

**Set a pod version in Podfile**

```
//specific version
pod '<framework_name>', "<semantic_versioning>"
// for example
pod 'MyFramework', "1.0"
```

Answer (score 28):

### If you have Installed `Cocoapods` using `Homebrew` then only use This Command:

```
pod --version
```

and it should show in this format:

```
1.11.0
```

Answer (score 18):

You can figure out version of Cocoapods by using below command :

```
pod —-version
```

**o/p :** `1.2.1`

Now if you want detailed version of *Gems and Cocoapods* then use below command :

`gem which cocoapods` **(without sudo)**

**o/p :** `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods.rb`

`sudo gem which cocoapods` **(with sudo)**

**o/p :** `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods.rb`

[image: Screenshot 1]

Now if you want to get **specific version of Pod present in Podfile** then simply use command `pod install` in terminal. This will show list of pod being used in project along with version.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a small commandline tool that parses the Podfile.lock and shows which version of each Pod is currently installed. It will also check for the latest version online and give you a summary of dependencies which are out-of-date.

You can find it on Github: https://github.com/citruz/podchecker

Comment: Dependencies with unknown state:
Getting above message for the latest framework updated. just like
-----------------------------------------
Dependencies with unknown state:
Facebook: 4.1.0 (Couldn't determine installed version)
GoogleAnalytics: 3.13.0 (Couldn't determine installed version)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm always getting "The contents of this script should nerev run! ...". Any ideas, toffifee? I do have perl installed.

Comment: Sorry I cannot reproduce your error. Do you have node.js/npm installed and did you run `npm install -g podchecker` to install the tool?

Answer (score 4):

The highest voted answer (MishieMoo) is correct but it doesn't explain how to **open Podfile.lock**. Everytime I tried I kept getting:

[image]

You open it in terminal by going to the folder it's in and running:

```
vim Podfile.lock
```

I got the answer from here: [how to open Podfile.lock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308841/4833705)

You close it by pressing the colon and typing quit or by pressing the colon and the letter q then enter

```
:quit // then return key
:q // then return key
```

Another way is in terminal, you can also cd to the folder that your Xcode project is in and enter

$ `open Podfile.lock -a Xcode`

Doing it the second way, after it opens just press the red X button in the upper left hand corner to close.

Comment: An easier and safer approach, as you don't touch the actual file:
* duplicate podfile.lock in finder.
* select dup'd file
* right click, select Open With... TextEdit

Comment: `open Podfile.lock -a TextEdit`.

Comment: Just open it in any text editor.  Drag the file onto any text editor that exists and its contents will open up and be easily understandable.

Answer (score 2):

**Podfile.lock** file right under Podfile within your project.

The main thing is , **Force it to open** through your favourite TextEditor, like Sublime or TextEdit [Open With -> Select Sublime] as it doesn't give an option straight away to open.

Answer (score 2):

**There are two way to know Pod version:**

**pod --version**

> 1.10.1

**gem which cocoapods**

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods.rb

Comment: Only `pod --version` works for me, I wonder if it's because I installed cocoapods via brew?

Answer (score 1):

To check the installed versions of your project's pods you can use the command `pod outdated` and as mentioned from [CocoaPods Guides](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html)

The output of each line will show you everything that you need such as:
`- <pod name> <current version> -> <latest version (with restrictions)> (latest version <latest version (without restrictions)>)`

So **current version** is the installed one, the next one is the latest **with the restrictions in your Podfile** and the last one **the available version without the restrictions**.

Answer (score 0):

**pod --version**
used this to check the version of the last installed pod

Answer (score -2):

You can check all installed pod version by this command in terminal

gem list -- local | grep cocoapods

Comment: I guess this command fully uninstalls the Cocoapods from the Mac Machine