# How to find out the version of installed cocoa pods?

Tags: macos, cocoapods

How to find out the version of installed cocoa pods?

I'm not asking about the version of the cocoa pods *gem*, but the version of the pods themselves. Ideally it would say "pod GreatViewController is installed in version 1.2.3, new version available: 1.2.6".

Is there something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a version of a CocoaPods framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931091/how-to-check-a-version-of-a-cocoapods-framework)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based on your clarification you're looking for `pod outdated`. You can see more information about this with `pod outdated --help`

**Original answer before question was edited**

The command you want is `pod --version`

In the future you should use `pod --help` to find answers such as this. You can also use `pod COMMAND --help` to get help for specific commands.

Comment: this is not the answer to the above question.

Comment: Thanks Keith. It took me awhile to see that I seemed to have another problem with Cocoapods not accepting my target name. But your anser is right

Comment: You should open another question if you can't find a solution!

Comment: The Podfile.lock keeps track of the resolved versions of each Pod installed.

Note: You should not edit this file. It is auto-generated when you run pod install or pod update

Comment: This is wrong. If you have the latest versions, `pod outdated` prints `No pod updates are available.`

Comment: The question was specifically for updating the pods. In the case where you just want to see your installed version you should check your `Podfile.lock`

Comment: actually, the answer `pod --version` is exactly what I'm looking for when I arrive at this QA.

Comment: The answer doesn't work when the specific goal is to list all installed versions in a user friendly manner. Like another comment said, it displays `No pod updates are available` .

Answer (score 85):

You will find the version # in your Podfile.lock of all the pods you are currently using in your project. You will find this file at the same location as your Podfile.

This is how mine looks like:

```
PODS:
  - Alamofire (3.4.1)
  - EPSignature (1.0.2)
  - Kingfisher (2.4.2)
  - MBProgressHUD (0.9.2)
  - SwiftyJSON (2.3.2)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Alamofire (~> 3.4)
  - EPSignature
  - Kingfisher
  - MBProgressHUD (~> 0.9.1)
  - SwiftyJSON

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Alamofire: 01a82e2f6c0f860ade35534c8dd88be61bdef40c
  EPSignature: 1f925f20b837046de46b4d396bc6e432ea383908
  Kingfisher: 05bf8d04408aaa70fcd2c8c81b9f1d0f1ad313dd
  MBProgressHUD: 1569cf7ace17a8bac47aabfbb8580a49690386d1
  SwiftyJSON: 04ccea08915aa0109039157c7974cf0298da292a

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 95eb36b090480f40d91543881d6ddb76bb1b8ca8

COCOAPODS: 1.0.1
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. That's why I downvoted the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18):

To get the version of cocoa pods

```
pod --version
```

To get the version of your pod, look in the Podfile.lock

When you install or update the pod, you can see the versions of both.

Answer (score 12):

if You are finding the version of a particular pod installed, then follow below steps:

> 1. Open Xcode
> 2. Click on "Project Navigator"
> 3. Click on "Pods"
> 4. Open The Pod you wanna know the version of
> 5. Expand it
> 6. Expand the "Supporting Files" folder
> 7. Click On yourpodname.plist
> 8. Read the Bundle Version string, short

Comment: this is the correct answer for latest Xcode project

Answer (score 11):

Open Terminal.

Change directory to your project and type the following `command` to open the `Podfile.lock` file.

```
$ open Podfile.lock -a Xcode
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pod search pod_name
```

example

```
pod search Alamofire
```

So you should have the pod name to use this command and it will give you a response like the following in the command line

> -> Alamofire (4.7.3)
>      Elegant HTTP Networking in Swift
>      pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7.3'
>      - Homepage: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire
>      - Source:   https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git
>      - Versions: 4.7.3, 4.7.2, 4.7.1, 4.7.0, 4.6.0, 4.5.1, 4.5.0, 4.4.0, 4.3.0,
>      4.2.0, 4.1.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.0, 3.5.1, 3.5.0, 3.4.2, 3.4.1, 3.4.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.0,
>      3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.5, 3.1.4, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.0,
>      3.0.0-beta.3, 3.0.0-beta.2, 3.0.0-beta.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0-beta.4,
>      2.0.0-beta.3, 2.0.0-beta.2, 2.0.0-beta.1, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1,
>      1.2.0, 1.1.5, 1.1.4, 1.1.3 [master repo]