# How do I check cocoapods version?

Tags: ios, version, cocoapods

How do I check cocoapods version?

I looked in the official site - 
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

but found only how to install \ update the latest version, or solving versions conflicts of installed gems etc'...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
$pod --version
```

Gives you the version. found it on this guide here:

https://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/11/updating-cocoapods/

Comment: Depending on your setup you may need `bundle exec pod --version`

Answer (score 25):

To check version of cocoapods from terminal:

For sudoless:

```
gem which cocoapods
```

For sudo:

```
sudo gem which cocoapods
```

[My previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31177514/3840428)