# How can I open Podfile for editing

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I used `CocoaPods` with my app I noticed I can't open `pod file` and the file turn to `exec` file like the image down, I need to edit it to add new libraries.

[image]

Comment: use `nano` from terminal, or just drag and drop inside `text editor` like `sublime`

Comment: Right click on that and choose Open With option in that you can open your Podfile in TextEditor or TextWrangler.

Comment: If you have the CocoaPods app installed: `open Podfile -a CocoaPods` from the Podfile directory in Terminal will open the Podfile for editing in the app.

I'm not sure why this question was locked for being too broad. It is not too broad if the question asker has no idea where to start, which is a valid position to be in.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Open the Podfile with TextEdit**
use terminal

```
 $ cd "your_project_location"
 $ open -a TextEdit Podfile
```

Comment: thanks its help  (-:

Comment: Isn't textedit known to replace certain characters like " and ' with different ones? And corrupting the file because of this? Would recommend `open -a Xcode Podfile` instead

Comment: It is recommended to use Xcode for editing Podfile rather than TextEdit since characters such as quotes are completely different in these two.

Comment: I have a project in swift 2.3 version which has podfile in exec format.I want to upgrade it to swift 3.0 including podfiles.What are the steps I want to follow?

Answer (score 13):

Open file from Terminal

`vim Podfile`

Comment: how do u save it ??I use :q! to come out but it says didn't find any podfile

Comment: @Akshay use `:wq`

Comment: @Yakiv Kovalsky this is the correct answer to open it.

Comment: You can also use "vi <filename>" or "sudo vi <filename>" for system config files. After pressing enter the file will open and press i to enter into insert mode only then you will able to edit the file after editing press Escape key then use :wq to save and exit.

Answer (score 12):

I think you will try these steps :

1- $ cd Your file location

2- $ open -a Xcode Podfile

Answer (score 5):

**1.open podfile from terminal**

```
$ cd "your_project_location that contain podfile"
$ nano Podfile
```

**2.You can also open podfile using xcode**

Right click to podfile and choose openwith xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop it to TextEdit or open project in XCode and edit there.