# how to check if the pod version is compatible with the Xcode version

Tags: swift

how could I check or know the version of a pod that is with the current version of my xcode, I am migrating from Xcode 11.6 to 12.2 and then there is a way to check these dependencies since I get multiple errors and as I have many pods, I am something complicated I will appreciate your help very much thanks for your time

Comment: Check this answer this might help you. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931091/how-to-check-version-of-a-cocoapods-framework**

Answer (score 1):

and If you want to install the specific version of the pod then after your pod name add this **'~> your version'**

Comment: What I want to know is the lowest version but compatible with the version of my Xcode, not the last current version, I will have to modify many parts of the code for that reason I want to check if the version of that pod is compatible with the Xcode version