# Non open-source cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Is it required for a cocoapod framework to be open source?
I have created a cocoapod swift framework on git.

And when I create an ios application and config the pod information in my Podfile.

It works fine.Now I want to protect my source code, expect other guys can use my 
framework, but can not see my framework source code.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. You can create a framework, compile it and distribute as a cocoapod. Use the `vendored_framework` or `vendored_frameworks` key in your podspec. An example podspec is the [Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK) pod that is distributed exactly that way.

```
{
  "name": "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK",
  "version": "7.6.0",
  "summary": "Monetize your mobile applications with Google ads",
  "description": "The Google Mobile Ads SDK is the latest generation in Google mobile advertising featuring refined ad formats and streamlined APIs for access to mobile ad networks and advertising solutions.",
  "homepage": "https://developers.google.com/admob/",
  "license": {
    "type": "Copyright",
    "text": "Copyright 2011 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved."
  },
  "authors": "Google Inc.",
  "platforms": {
    "ios": "6.0"
  },
  "source": {
    "http": "https://dl.google.com/googleadmobadssdk/googlemobileadssdkios-7.6.0.zip"
  },
  "preserve_paths": "GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.6.0",
  "vendored_frameworks": "GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.6.0/GoogleMobileAds.framework",
  "weak_frameworks": "AdSupport",
  "frameworks": [
    "AudioToolbox",
    "AVFoundation",
    "CoreGraphics",
    "CoreMedia",
    "CoreTelephony",
    "EventKit",
    "EventKitUI",
    "MessageUI",
    "StoreKit",
    "SystemConfiguration"
  ],
  "requires_arc": true
}
```

Comment: you mean I need to add the 'vendored_frameworks' line in my podspec? How about the value of it, I can not understand well what is this property used for.

Comment: "vendored_frameworks" is used to integrate third custom framework, why will it protect my source non-open.

Comment: Do not include source code in your pod, only the compiled framework.

Comment: only add the 'vendored_frameworks' property will work? What should be its value? My .framework path?And where the path is relative to?

Comment: Take a look at the example. The compiled framework is uploaded to some server, there is no source code at all.

Comment: I tried to upload my .framework to the git as part of my source.

Comment: I tried to upload my .framework to the git as part of my source. And when I add my framework pod in my another project podfile. and then run 'pod update' will download my framework and I see only .framework folder contains Frameworks sub sub folder (inlcude some .dylib files) and Headers sub folder (include test.h file and test-Swfit.h file), I can import my framework, but can not use method or instantiate my public swift class in the framework

Comment: Any tutorial links for me?

Comment: It seems like there is something wrong with your framework itself. For tutorials check [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com).

Comment: That is not relevant. If you have issues with creating a framework, please ask another question.

Comment: see [create a swift framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630048/custom-swift-framework-create-with-other-dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

**CocoaPods closed source**

`CocoaPods`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218904/4770877) supports `open source` and `closed source(binary)` distribution

To create `closed source` you should

1. Create a `fat binary`[<sup>[Vocabulary]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877) - to allow working with it on simulator and real device
2. Zip and publish(e.g. zip attachment for GitHub)

The key point is to use parameters in your `podspec`:

- `source` - http link to a `.zip` file with a fat binary
- `vendored_frameworks` - path to your framework in the `.zip` file pointed by the `source`

Take a look at guidelines [here](https://medium.com/@mkeremkeskin/distributing-closed-source-frameworks-with-cocoapods-and-carthage-44fd141cfd78), [here](https://www.tirupatibalan.com/2019/01/10/publish-closed-source-framework-cocoapods-ios.html)