# iOS Dynamic Framework for Carthage and Cocoa pods dependent on other frameworks

Tags: ios, cocoapods, dynamic-library, carthage

I'm totally new to iOS Framework development.

I've made a framework project which is dependent on JSONModel and AFNetworking.

Now I need to distribute this framework through cocoa pods and carthage.

What are the steps that I should take to make that possible, especially how do I deal with dependencies towards JSONModel and AFNetworking in both: Cocoa Pods and Carthage ways?

Answer (score 0):

`Cocoapods`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218904/4770877) and `Cartage` as dependency manager[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257708/4770877) support `dynamic framework`. Cocoapods work with `podspec`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812997/4770877) and `Carthage` work with `cartfile`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61397563/4770877)

You can start with official docs [Cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html) [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#supporting-carthage-for-your-framework)