# Why is pod repo update required when you fetch the latest versions directly from the internet?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I read [What exactly does `pod repo update` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701352/what-exactly-does-pod-repo-update-do), but my question is: if in my podfile, I specify I want version 1.5 of a pod and that pod is available in its own repo, then why doesn't my project try to fetch the latest version straight from internet?

Why do I need to update my repo locally to make it happen?

Is it an intentional to make it a two step ie 1. to update your podfile, 2. update your local Cocoapods so I'd be thoughtful and reduce chances of an incompatible update blowing up in my face?