# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleSignIn": In Podfile: GoogleSignIn

Tags: ios, cocoapods

How to solve this error ?

My Podfile looks like this :

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
end
```

Comment: Check the below link *https://stackoverflow.com/a/72813307/14266627*
it's a version problem

Answer (score 5):

First step, you could check if the pod repo needs an update. Use the below command to update :

```
pod repo update
```

Post that, try deleting "Podfile.lock" file and "Pods" folder inside your project directory. And then run the below commands in sequence :

```
pod deintegrate
 
pod install
 
pod update
```

Comment: I have a question! What does actually 'pod repo update' work for?

Comment: Please check this stack overflow post for your question on pod repo update : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701352/what-exactly-does-pod-repo-update-do#:~:text=As%20per%20the%20documentation%20pod,of%20the%20spec%2Drepo%20NAME.&text=By%20running%20pod%20repo%20update,can%20continue%20to%20install%20it.