# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleSignIn"

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, google-signin

[image]

I was facing this issue when I was trying to install pods in my react-native project.

Answer (score 5):

`cd ios` then  `pod update GoogleSignIn`.
it will update automatically.

Comment: in 2024,
check the code below in `./ios/Podfile`
`platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '14.0'`