# Flutter: build ios failed with no errors

Tags: ios, flutter

Last week I was able to build without any problems, but now when I try to build for iOS it fails with 165k rows of warnings and no errors. All the warnings talk about deprecated methods in the packages I use, but it has never been a problem until this week.
I've not changed any version (flutter, packages, xCode), the only edit that I've made is the firebase messagging configuration, but even if I remove it the build fails.
What I've tried:

- flutter clean
- remove Podfile.lock
- undone the edits

Any ideas to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the app with

```
Flutter run -v
```

-v is used to output verbosely so if there are any missing logs it will show there. As you talked about 165k lines of warnings, it may be helpful to search "error:" in the terminal console to find a log about an error.
I remember once it happened to me and the reason was Pod update.

[What exactly does `pod repo update` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701352/what-exactly-does-pod-repo-update-do)

Comment: already searched for "error".
I don't know so much about pods, Is it possible that they updated themselves?

Comment: cd into "ios" directory in the flutter project folder and run "pod repo update" and then "pod install" commands

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
1. open Runner.xcworkspace via xcode
2. Product tab > Clean build folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: after updating Flutter to the latest version the error desappered. I don't know what caused it, but it still makes no sense to me