# Duplicate interface definition for class 'FIRConfiguration'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I have two errors and I have been trying to figure them out. I am using Xcode and also trying to run my project with a minimum deploy meant of IOS 14. I how my Coco pods up to date and I am not sure what to do with this error. below, I have included pictures of the two error and also the code.

[image: Error Messages]

[image: First Problem Code]

[image: Second Problem Code]

here is my pod file:

#Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

#platform :iOS, '14.0'

target 'Chall Champ' do use_frameworks!

pod ‘Appirater’

pod ‘Firebase/Core’

pod ‘Firebase/Auth’

pod ‘Firebase/Database’

pod ‘Firebase/Analytics’

pod ‘Firebase/Crashlytics’

pod ‘Firebase/Storage’

end

Comment: I have run into this before and there are several causes; It could be an incorrectly setup podFile or outdated podfile, so we would need to see that. On that same topic, your cocoapods maybe outdated (you didnt include the version) Again, including the podfile and versions of your development tools would help.? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I have updated my pods to the most resent one which is 10.1 or something around that. and what do you mean I could have set up my pod file wrong? also, I was able to work on this project a couple of weeks back and everything would run with the pod file I already had. so I don't know what could have gone wrong

Comment: "incorrectly setup podfile" literally means, the code in the podifle, or the files referenced or HOW they are referenced could be causing an issue. It's customary to include the podfile in questions (if the issue may be related) to add clarity about what's being loaded/versions etc. It just makes troubleshooting easier for us since we have more datapoints. I don't see any answers and theres a close vote (not by me) so adding details may prevent the question from being closed. Just trying to help...

Comment: I added my pod file to the post, did I do it wrong?

Comment: Ok. it's not wrong, but it is outdated. The new implementation is: instead of '‘Firebase/Core', use 'FirebaseCore'. You should add `FirebaseFirestore`. Read more on the newer set up [Firebase Pods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize-firebase). You may want to consider `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install` on the project as well. Lastly, the cocopods repository may need to be refreshed. Oh, and if you want to use codable, include `pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '~> 9.0.0'`

Comment: ok, are you able to give me an example of what you mean. this is my first time using cocopods and also podfiles. I kind of understand what your saying but not fully

Comment: and what do you mean when you say the cocopods repository may need to be refreshed?

Comment: It's likely unrelated but for reference: this `$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods` updates cocoapods. And then the repo would be `pod repo update` and then `pod update`

Comment: oh ok, are you able to explain what pod repo does?

Comment: and this is what you think my pod file should be for me to be able to run my project and also have all of the normal apple viewing functions :

Comment: # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'Chall Champ' do
    use_frameworks!

pod ‘Appirater’

pod ‘FirebaseCore’
pod ‘Firebase/Auth’
pod ‘Firebase/Database’
pod ‘Firebase/Analytics’
pod ‘Firebase/Crashlytics’
pod ‘Firebase/Storage’                                                         
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '~> 9.0.0'

end

Comment: I ask because since switching my pod file, I haven't been able to switch between lightened dark mode while running it in simulator.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments as it's hard to read and anything question related should be put *in the question* as formatted code. A podfile is 100% unrelated to dark/light mode. There's a LOT of information on the [cocoapods website](https://cocoapods.org), on the internet and here on SO about cocoapods. It would be too much info and off topic to explain it here in comments but a quick search reveals [What does pod repo do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701352/what-exactly-does-pod-repo-update-do). Please review the Firebase link as `Firebase/Auth` (and the others) are outdated.