# [Difference]: Static, Dynamic Library and Static, Dynamic framework. + Library and Framework in iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, shared-libraries, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I have read so many articles about these topics on so many sites including stack overflow that I am so confused now which information is correct one and which is not. Can anybody help me to understand the concept of all five things mentioned in the title or share some authentic link from where I can easily understand what all these things are actually.

Secondly, I want to understand that when we use Cocoapods to use some third party library like Alamofire, Is it a dynamic framework or static? and If we directly drag and drop Alamofire's source folder directly into my project Will it be considered as dynamic or static frajmework/library still at that time?

Answer (score 0):

As for differences between libraries and frameworks, static and dynamic linking you can read [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877).

As for `Cocoapods`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218904/4770877) it depends on setting `use_frameworks!`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257384/4770877) in podfile

When you dragndrop binary you should be provided with some instruction form author, [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216858/4770877)