# Podspec - Exclude all but a subfolder

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, cakefile

I have a structure like this

```
target_files/
├──target1/
├──target2/
└──target3/
```

And I want to include only "target2" for example and exclude the other targets. How I write the spec.exclude_files?

I found this example for excluding files, but I can't understand how to write it for whole folders.

spec.exclude_files = '_private/**/*.{h,m}'

Answer (score 11):

```
spec.source_files = [ 'target_files/**' ]
spec.exclude_files = [ 'target_files/target1/**', 'target_files/target3/**' ]
```

or for the case you ask about, more simply:

```
spec.source_files = [ 'target_files/target2/**' ]
```

[Reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#group_file_patterns)

Comment: My fault. I didn't explain that I must write it in an "exclude form", because that target2 is variable. 

I can't simply choose what to include, because tomorrow I can add a target3, target4... and I don't want to add things there. I only want to write something like "pick targetX and exclude all other targets".

Answer (score 5):

**CocoaPods exclude_files**

[[CocoaPods]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218904/4770877)

`Pattern: **` - Matches directories recursively.

```
s.exclude_files = 'target_files/target1/', 'target_files/target3/'
```

The opposite is `source_files`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257783/4770877)